# ASP.NET client with node.js / socket.io server

Tags: asp.net, node.js, socket.io

Is it possible to communicate from an ASP.NET application to a node.js server?

To start with, I'd just like to be able to see the connections.  I assumed that something like this would work:

**Server (node.js):**

```
var io = require('socket.io').listen(1234);

io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket)
{
    console.log('connected');

    socket.on('disconnect', function ()
    {
        console.log('disconnected');
    });
});
```

**Client (ASP.NET):**

```
var tcpClient = new System.Net.Sockets.TcpClient();
tcpClient.Connect("localhost", 1234);
System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000);
tcpClient.Close();
```

...but I'm not having much joy.  The client doesn't complain at all, but I never see 'connected' or 'disconnected' printed in node.js.

Has anyone got something like this working?

Comment: Have you tried using var httpReq = System.Net.HttpWebRequest.Create("http://localhost:1234") instead?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I'm not sure how that would work though - as far as I know you wouldn't want to keep a HTTP request open like you would with a socket. I tried anyway but it doesn't seem to work either :(